# Unitary Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Suppose A is a unitary operator, a is the annhilation operator in usual sense and we know the value of the quantity, $A^{\dagger}aA$.
Then how would I calculate the value of the quantity,
$AaA^{\dagger}$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ‘‘calculate the values of the quantity $AaA^\dagger$? This non-scalar value will depend on whag $A$ is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a unitary operator we have that:
$$AA^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}A=I,$$
where $I$ is the identity operator. So given that $B=A^{\dagger}aA$, we can apply $A$ to the left:
$$AB=AA^{\dagger}aA=IaA=aA.$$
Now apply $A$ to the left again:
$$A^2B=AaA.$$
Next let $A^{\dagger}$ act on the right to get:
$$A^2BA^{\dagger}=AaAA^{\dagger}=Aa.$$
Finally, act on the right with $A^{\dagger}$:
$$A^2B(A^{\dagger})^2=AaA^{\dagger}.$$